# Sharing an updatable, serialised xml file between multiple programs

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I have a set of related applications, which all use the same xml file for their settings. I currently use an XmlSerializer to load the file on program start.

I now have a requirement to update the settings file from within the applications. Clearly the existing code won't work, as all the currently running applications will have the same xml data, as loaded when they started, and each program will overwrite the file with the original values, plus only its own changes.

What is the best way to deal with this as simply as possible?

Requirements are:

- The settings file must be human-readable and editable.
- I don't want to read the whole settings file every time I access an
  element of the settings object.
- I want the settings class to be easy to write and alter - it is
  currently just a list of properties, a method that reads it in from
  disk using XmlSerializer, and a method which writes it out again.

Comment: FileSystemWatcher is maybe you'll need

Comment: Just seperate the different applications by sections then load only the section require by the application.

Comment: are the settings unique to each application? are there settings common to all applications?

Comment: There are settings mainly used by a particular application, and also common settings.

Comment: FileSystemWatcher can tell me the file has been updated by another application. But what do I do with the information? I might have altered some settings in this application (but not saved them yet), so re-reading the whole thing is no good.

Comment: This makes me wonder if an xml file is the right answer, and maybe I should be using INI files, and reading/writing individual elements every time I need them (like old Windows programs used to).